# Dynamic build query & SQL Injection & DLLs files

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, dll, dll-injection

I have read a lot of things about SQL injection and many arguments why you should avoid to build your query dynamically using plain code/concatenations within your cs.file

However, I have question and I need some advice from someone with more experience than me.

I created some DLL files in order to re-use my code in different projects and for that reason I was thinking generic.

I created these DLL files that contained all the logic/code of building SQL queries in a dynamic way + concatenation of statement. Thereafter, I add these DLL files as reference to my project.

This will be vulnerable to SQL Injection ? also is that insufficient procedure (time consuming/insufficient maintenance)?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: i guess your problem starts when f.e. the tables or fields are dynamic like this: `string sql = "SELECT " + sColumns + " FROM " + sTableName;` ?   you cant parameterize tablenames out of the box. its recommended to use sp_exectutesql in these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not processing your input that you are passing to your query (built at run time) you are vulnerable to SQL injection. Adding to dll or not doesn't makes any difference.

To overcome this you need to use parameterised queries. They have multiple advantages a part from security.

One reason that i can think of right now is that you have a text box. And your query is

```
 "select * from table1 where name = '" +  textbox1.Text;
```

Not lets assume that in textbox1 user enters `Ehsan's`. Your query will go bang and won't even execute.

Example of parameterised query

```
 "select * from table1 where name = @Name"
 yourCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textbox1.Text);
```

Comment: "Processing my input" ? For example, by putting some validation rules on my inputs ?

Comment: Yes you need to validate your input for all the possible mischiefs a hacker can perform. Or simply use stored procedures or parameterised queries that will ensure that your parameters are getting the right values.

Comment: thank you Ehsan, however can I replace parameterized queries & stored procedures with DLL files including dynamic SQL queries ? and keep the security as well ?

Comment: @michaalis sorry i didn't get your question. if you mean that can you add parameterized queries in dll files then surely you can.

Comment: i meant, by adding dynamic queries like your example above (with textbox) in a DLL file, is it secure ?

Comment: @michaalis i have given this example to show that it is not secure. I will add another example to show what is secure. I have added an example of what is secure.

Comment: @michaalis Whether your queries are in a dll or not does not affect vulnerability to SQL injection, SQL injection vuln occurs when a variable used to concatenate your SQL string comes from input.  In my example answer if somevar = "null; sql to inject" then you have a SQL injection attack.

Comment: @michaalis glad we were of any help.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know for sure but if you do something like

```
string sql = "SELECT Field FROM Table WHERE Field = " + Somevar;
```

Then you are open to SQL injection if somevar comes from input of some kind (usually user input).

There is just no reason to do it as you can just do

```
string sql = "SELECT Field FROM Table WHERE Field = @myvar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you are using parameterized queries or stored procedures, etc.

And avoid using dynamic SQL queries such as

```
"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = " + UserID
```

as these are vulnerable to SQL Injection

Instead use a parameterized query or a stored procedure, e.g.

```
"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = @UserID"
```

Most ORMs (eg .NET's Entity Framework) will provide some protection against SQL Injection (but only if used properly)

this link explains in more detail http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html

Comment: So, as I understand I cannot replace parameterized queris & stored procedues with DLL files including dynamic SQL queries ? to keep the security :)

Comment: If you wrote the code for the dll files, then I don't see any reason why you couldn't